# Django, Axax PUT 400 Bad request

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I have a problem with Django (rest) and ajax, when I try to send the data of a form with the method (PUT), in the browser console sends me an error (PUT '/ url / api / 1', 400 Bad request) , before coming and ask I started to investigate about this error and in many other posts give as a solution to use "JSON.stringify" to convert to json the form with the data to update, I have tried this and it did not work, another is use - contentType: "application / json; charset = utf-8", - but it did not work either, someone who can help me?

my views.py

```
class pacienteDetail(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return modelsHC.Paciente.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except modelsHC.Paciente.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        paciente = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = pacienteSerializer(paciente)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        paciente = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = pacienteSerializer(paciente, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        paciente = self.get_object(pk)
        paciente.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

class pacientesList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = modelsHC.Paciente.objects.all()
    serializer_class = pacienteSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = pacienteSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

my form.html

```
  <form class="form-edit" action="{% url 'core:paciente_detail' pk=paciente.pk%}">{% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                    <label for="id_first_name">Nombre(s)</label>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="id_first_name" value="">

                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <label for="id_last_name">Apellidos</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="id_last_name" value="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

and my script

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'PUT',
                  url: $(".form-edit").attr('action'),
                  data: $(".form-edit").serialize(),
                  //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dateType: 'json',
                  success: function(res) {
                    console.log(res)
                  },
                  error: function(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                  }
                });
              });
```

I'm using a script for csrf...
I'm trying with "type: 'POST'" but my api endpoint does't allow the POST method, only get, update and delte

and this is the error when I click the save button.
[image: This is the error]

Answer (score 0):

Is there any data in the body of the server response? Looking at your code, if the serializer's call to `is_valid` returns `False`, you will return a 400 status code, with `serializer.errors`.

Furthermore, do you see anything in the server error logs?

Can you reproduce the same behavior using a simple REST client (such as curl or postman), to eliminate the possibility that your JS is doing something incorrect with it's request?

Comment: In the server log only show "PUT /url/...." HTTP/1.1 400 and with postman is working

Comment: What about the response body of the request?